# filter and return row, first row always get returned, vba

Tags: vba, excel, filter, copying

I have a combo box with a value that I would like to be searched for in another workbook column. The code using autofilter then returns the rows which have that value in the same column(column 4).
It works correctly however the first row of the source is always being copied over to the destination, weather it does or doesn't not have the value being looking for in the specific column.
The offset or cell shifting is being used as the first two row in both sheets are headers

```vb
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Look in data repository for the Combobox filter value and only return those associated rows (can be more than one)

Dim DataBlock As Range, Dest As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim SheetOne As Worksheet, SheetTwo As Worksheet
Dim PN As String
PN = ComboBox1.Value

'set references up-front
Set SheetTwo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report") 'this is the expiditing report
Set SheetOne = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Nexen\Data Repository V1.xlsm").Sheets("Data") 'this is the expiditing report
Set Dest = SheetTwo.Cells(3, 1) '<~ this is where we'll put the filtered data

'identify the "data block" range, which is where
'the rectangle of information that Ill apply
'.autofilter to
With SheetOne
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set DataBlock = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    'Set DataBlock = Range("A3:AV65000") 'for testing
End With

'apply the autofilter to column D (i.e. column 4)
With DataBlock
    'can use offset .Offset(2, 0).
    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=PN
    'copy the still-visible cells to sheet 2
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Dest
End With

'turn off the autofilter
With SheetOne
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    If .FilterMode = True Then .ShowAllData
End With

End Sub

Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim MyBook As String
Dim MyRange As Range
    'Get name of current wb
    MyBook = ThisWorkbook.Name
  Set MyRange = MyBook.Sheets("Report").Range("T3,AC65000")

'ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
 MyBook.Activate


End Sub
```

![etr][1]

So why am i getting the first row back regardless? I have tried a multitude of things.

Comment: `.Offset(1, 0).Resize(LastRow - 1, LastCol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Dest`

Comment: try with `.CurrentRegion` when copying, something like `With DataBlock (...).CurrentRegion.Copy Dest` which, based on my experience, is much better than `.SpecialCells` in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.Range` needs to be in a `Table` with a header for `AutoFilter` to work properly.